# Jquery input selects on blur

Tags: jquery, html, focus, blur

Is there any ways to select text or focus on input on BLUR event?

The purpose is that the name on text field is unique and they tab to save it. So I validate if it exists, then select that text for user to put other.

Helps or suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You could either wipe the value of the input, or try using the `.select()` function: `$('#INPUTID').select();`

Comment: Can you post your codes please?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [.select() function](http://api.jquery.com/select/):

```
$("#inputField").blur(function(){
 // Validate the username..
    var validuser = false;

    if(!validuser){
        $(this).select(); // or $('#InputID').select();
    }

});
```

would result in something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/z0Lgrj54/5/)

Comment: If you type something into the first input box and tab/click out of it, validation fails and the first input should gain focus and the text highlighted. That's fine. `this` is not a requirement, the `$('#ID')` selector can also be used.

Comment: This example works on tab, how about click outside text field? It's called blur but not focus.

Comment: @TranTam Clicking outside the field is also a trigger for [.blur() function](http://api.jquery.com/blur/) `An element can lose focus via keyboard commands, such as the Tab key, or by mouse clicks elsewhere on the page`